# Unable to run mix google_apis.auth task

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, elixir

I am trying to integrate an Elixir application with Google Drive using the `elixir-google-api`.

According to the docs there is a mix task, google_apis.auth, that can be used to create a token, however, mix is unable to find that task. Do I need to add something additional to my mix.exs?

````
defp deps do
    [
     {:ecto_sql, "~> 3.0"},
     {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
     {:account_service, in_umbrella: true},
     {:jason, "~> 1.1"},
     {:google_api_drive, "~> 0.11.0"},
     {:goth, "~> 1.2"}
    ]
  end```

Thanks,
Peter
````

Comment: Just to confirm, you ran `mix deps.get`?

Comment: Yes... I have ran mix deps.get

Answer (score 0):

That [auth task](https://github.com/googleapis/elixir-google-api/blob/master/lib/mix/tasks/google_apis.auth.ex) seems to be present in the [main google_api project](https://github.com/googleapis/elixir-google-api) but not in the [drive client project](https://github.com/googleapis/elixir-google-api/tree/master/clients/drive) that you are using.

Never used those libraries so I don't know what is best practice here; use the main `elixir-google-api` project or the generated client library.

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution to get a token in Elixir.

At first I followed this: https://github.com/googleapis/elixir-google-api#obtaining-an-access-token.

But you can create a Service Account for your application and download the private key in json format. https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts. Before you use it the Drive Api must be enabled by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/drive.googleapis.com/overview.

and put some line to `config/config.exs` file:

```rb
config :goth,
  json: "full_path_of_your_service_account_private_key.json" |> File.read!
```

Example:

```rb
def drive_connect() do
   {:ok, token} = Goth.Token.for_scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive")
   connection = GoogleApi.Drive.V3.Connection.new(token.token)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The `google_apis.auth` task doesn't exist in any mix package (at least, I couldn't find it).

For being able to create a token, you need to clone the repo and change directory:

```
git clone git@github.com:googleapis/elixir-google-api.git
cd elixir-google-api
```

Compile the application: `mix compile`

Then, execute the task according to the README:

```
mix google_apis.auth https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
```

Remember to `export` the `GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID` and `GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET` env vars.